# Why matrix[i+1][j] is not defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, matrix

Why matrix in [i+1] is not defined meanwhile it works properly for matrix [i]

```
 function matrixElementsSum(matrix) {
     let x = 0;
     let i = 0;
     let j=0;
     for (i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
         for (j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {

         if (matrix[i][j] === 0) {
             matrix[i+1][j]=0;
            //Cannot set property '0' of undefined
         }
         x = matrix[i].reduce(function(a,b){return a+b},0);
         x +=x;
      }

     }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Think about the case when `i` is `matrix.length-1` at that time there does not exists `i+1`

Comment: In the very last iteration of the outer loop, when `i == matrix.length - 1`, then `i + 1` will be out of bounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

The index - `i` - should go until `matrix.length - 1` in your

```
    for (i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
       ///ETC
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why matrix in [i+1] is not defined meanwhile it works properly for
>   matrix [i]

Simply because of your **for-loop condition**

```
for (i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
```

value of `i` can go upto `matrix.length -1`, and `matrix[ matrix.length ]` will always be `undefined` as [array indexing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description) starts from `0`.